# How to get UserName in a label in my Create.html?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I have an asp.net core 2.0 site using VS 2017 (ver. 15.4) & C#. I have a 'Comments' model that has been scaffoled. A user has to be logged in to create a new comment. In 'Create.cshtml' I want the 'Date' and the 'UserName' to be filled in a label- not an input. Just trying to keep a user from using a false name to create a comment. I need to use code in 'Create.html' to accomplish this. Here is what I have in 'Create.html':

Date (this works):

```html
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

UserName (this does NOT work) :

```html
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "control-label", @Value = User.Identity.Name } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the UserName filled in using a label. Thanks for any suggestions.     Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well couple problems on your approach:

1. There is no `value` attribute on a `label` element
2. Since you have the `ViewModel` for the `Create.cshtml` view, and you have a `UserName` property, there is no point to do `LabelFor` or `TextBoxFor` with no value and initialize the element value on the Razor view. You could have done so when initializing the `ViewModel` on the server side.

## Fix

You can initialize the model property `UserName` with the value of `User.Identity.Name` on the server side, and remove the `@value = User.Identity.Name` on the view.

### My 2 cents

If you just want to display the `UserName` and not expect it comes back as input, you don't have to put `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` there. You are not getting a value when doing post back anyway.

And for the same reason, you can just use a regular `<label>` element with Razor 1 way binding to display the value, i.e.,

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2">@Model.UserName</label>
</div>
```

I see you're using Bootstrap. There is a class from Bootstrap 4 called `form-control-plaintext` that will style an input element and make it look like a label, so that you can actually bind the value to an input as well.

```
<!-- Throwing in Tag Helper just for fun -->
<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="UserName" class="col-form-label col-md-2"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control-plaintext" asp-for="UserName"
            readonly />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could give you a hundred check marks.      Jeff